# Node "Not a dynamic executable"

Tags: command-line, nodejs

I'm running 14.04 on Linode and tried following [these instructions](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nodejs/installing-nodejs) to install NVM and then node. I can get NVM running just fine but installing Node results in cryptic "file not found" messages when I attempt to run it, even though the file is listed in the correct directory.

All the paths for NVM are correct, and there doesn't seem to be any conflicts (neither `node` or `nodejs` are listed in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin`), and I have tried running the executable with its full path.

I thought it could be a 32-bit binary issue, but running `file node` seems to suggest it is a 64-bit executable:

```
node: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
```

However, running `ldd node` on it gives the message:

```
not a dynamic executable
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing some shared libraries, but I have no idea what these could be.

Also, how would I find out if there are any dangling symbolic links?

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered the limitations of the (64 bit install) ldd script.  The least you would expect is the complaint of "wrong ELF class".  Install a few more 32 bit pieces like the 32 bit ld, and you might start getting some reasonable output (ld is the 32 bit loader).
The package needed for this is libc6-i386.

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately that package is no longer available (from APT at least). I think I'm going to just forgo nvm and install it manually.